# Historical data sets in an initial build

Tags: ssis, data-warehouse, scd

The issue I am currently facing is I think a logical one and maybe a limitation of SSIS.

My data has a set of accounts, at any point this account can be owned by an organisation. This combination controls my historical dimension of "Account"

E.g

```
╔════════════╦═══════════════╦════════════════╦════════════╦════════════╦═════════╗
║ AccountKey ║ AccountNumber ║ OrganisationSK ║ VaildFrom  ║ VaildTo    ║ Current ║
╠════════════╬═══════════════╬════════════════╬════════════╬════════════╬═════════╣
║ 1          ║ 2000          ║ 10             ║ 2000-01-01 ║ 2006-02-10 ║ N       ║
╠════════════╬═══════════════╬════════════════╬════════════╬════════════╬═════════╣
║ 2          ║ 2000          ║ 11             ║ 2006-02-10 ║ 2010-06-01 ║ N       ║
╠════════════╬═══════════════╬════════════════╬════════════╬════════════╬═════════╣
║ 3          ║ 2000          ║ 10             ║ 2010-06-01 ║ NULL       ║ Y       ║
╚════════════╩═══════════════╩════════════════╩════════════╩════════════╩═════════╝
```

Doing this is easy enough going forward as I just let the SCD do its thing, it is the initial load I am struggling with.

Using SSIS as my ETL tool, am I able to use an inner join, giving me the three records, sort them by "ValidFrom" and then pass all three to the SCD and SSIS will figure things out?

In this circumstance what have people done in the past?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an inner join within SSIS using the Merge Transformation. Link below:

- [Merge Join Transformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/merge-join-transformation?view=sql-server-2017])

One of the requirements for a merge join is to sort at least one column(s) you join on from both data sources so you can sort the data by the "ValidFrom" column that you require.

You can then connect the Merge Join output to your SCD transformation.

Please note that the Merge Join transformation is Semi-Blocking transformation so your ETL performance might be hindered if you are dealing with large amount of data.